# Why am I receiveing String index Out of Range: 97?

Tags: java, string, input, bounds

I programmed a Spanish Conjugator. For instance, if you click on the method `isItEr()`, then you input the word, and then you enter the letter associated with the form in a switch sampler.

The error is on the line of 'case a:'
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
String index out of range: 97 (in java.lang.string)

```
public void isItIr()
{
    System.out.print("Enter the infinitive: ");
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String infinitive = keyIn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    if(infinitive.substring(infinitive.length()-2, infinitive.length()).equals("ir"))
           word = conjugateEndingIr(infinitive);
}

private String conjugateEndingIr(String infinitive)
{
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Choose form: ");

    System.out.println("a. Yo");
    System.out.println("b. Tu");
    System.out.println("c. El/Ella/Usted");
    System.out.println("d. Nosotros");
    System.out.println("e. Ellos/Ellas/Ustedes");
    System.out.println("f. Exit program");

    System.out.print("Enter Choice => ");
    String input = keyIn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    char ch = input.charAt(0);

    if (!(ch >= 'a' && ch <='e'))
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Choice!!!");
        System.out.print("Please enter choice again => ");
        input = keyIn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        ch = input.charAt(0);
    }

    switch( ch)
    {
        case 'a': 
        char idxio = 'a';
        word = infinitive.substring(0, idxio) + "o";
        return word;
        case 'b': 
        char idxesi = 'a';
        word = infinitive.substring(0, idxesi) + "es";
        return word;
        case 'c':
        char idxei = 'a';
        word = infinitive.substring(0, idxei) + "e";
        return word;
        case 'd':
        char idximos = 'a';
        word = infinitive.substring(0, idximos) + "imos";
        return word;
        case 'e':
        char idxeni = 'a';
        word = infinitive.substring(0, idxeni) + "en";
        return word;
        case 'f':
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.exit(-1);
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid menu choice");
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return word;
}
```

`

When I input beber, it loads the switch sampler with the "choose form" and when I put 'a' I get an error that is stated in the title! How can I resolve this? Thanks~

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. This tells you (and us) what line causes the error.

Comment: A is the letter of the option on the switch sampler, not infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `'a'` is a character that your code reinterprets as its code point (which happens to be `97`).

When you do this

```
char idxio = 'a';
word = infinitive.substring(0, idxio) + "o";
```

the string attempts to take the first 97 characters in a word that is shorter than 97.

What you have probably meant was finding the index of the letter `'a'` starting at the end of the target word, chopping off the ending, and replacing it with an `'o'`. You can use [`lastIndexOf('a')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) for that:

```
int idxio = infinitive.lastIndexOf('a');
word = infinitive.substring(0, idxio) + "o";
```

Comment: Yes, I did intend that. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: @user2994631 Please see the last two lines of the answer.

Comment: It says that it cannot find symbol - method lastIndexOf(char). I don't have that method in my code, but I see where you are getting at.

Comment: @user2994631 Ah, of course, it's a method that needs to be called on the string from which you are removing the ending.

Comment: So, create the method? Sorry, not used to this substring

Comment: Okay, it says possible loss of precision, I assume this is because lastIndexOf would be int idxio, not a char.

Comment: @user2994631 Did the last edit fix your problem? If it did, please accept the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would indicate to other site visitors that you are no longer actively looking for help with this problem, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `String.substring`.  If you look at the Javadoc for the `String` class, you will see the `boolean endsWith(String suffix)` method.  Use the most natural and specific method.

You might also want to use the regular expression `(.*)ir$`; if it matches, the captured group is the base. In Spanish, can you determine the form of the conjugation from the word itself, instead of having the user intervene?

Comment: This would make a perfect comment, not an answer, because it explains OP how he could optimize what's already working (perhaps not as efficiently as it could) but it does not tell OP how to fix his problem.

Comment: No, because with beber the user can have it conjugated 5 different ways, just with 'beber'
Okay, so where do you mean to put endsWith? In case a?

Comment: I guess you're right.  The  `endsWith` would replace the substring code in the fourth line of `isItIr`.